# Difference between node-cron and setInterval()

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-cron

I need to repeat a backend task every hour. I've read that node-cron is good for that. But why not just setInterval(). What is the difference?

Comment: You could, however node-cron has built in ways to handle errors and other features. plus, it also runs on a node fork.

Comment: I think also the difference is that for cron there can be thrown errors, but the process will be continued, but for setInterval it will stop the whole process. Am I wrong ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `setInterval()` only allows you to set a repetition by a fixed value of milliseconds. nothing else.

With `cron-node` you are much more flexible, because you can set your interval with the full variety of time parts. Seconds, minutes, hours and so forth. It's a real scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

**node-corn** internally use Node's **setTimeout()** function for running jobs or backend tasks. The major advantage of this it is a **real scheduler**, for example, its  .start() and .stop() methods only when you need it, you can also specify the **timezone** in which the task should run.

on the other, The **setTimeout()** method calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds.